# Drinking pure olive oil

Tags: calories

I want to gain weight and I'm thinking about drinking large amounts of olive oil to get more calories in my body.

Is there an issue with drinking 100ml (~800 calories) at once?

Comment: Your question is off topic for the site.

Comment: Even if it wasn't off topic this is a typical [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/176874). You want to gain weight, but instead of asking how to do it you ask us to judge your solution. That specific solution off topic here, you might want to check out the [Nutrition proposal on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44550/nutrition), however.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this several times experimenting with ketogenic diets. I strongly recommend you start with a much smaller dose and work your way up, as drinking that much oil can cause nausea if you're not accustomed to it.

Something else to consider is that olive oil is high in Omega 6 EFAs, but is very low in Omega 3s. You may want to see if consuming EFAs with a messed up ratio could cause any health issues over time.

You may want to consider other oils such as cod liver oil and coconut oil.

When I was on my high fat diet, I actually found heavy cream (whipping cream, not whipped cream) to be the easiest solution. I mixed it with chocolate protein powder and it tastes great. The issue here could be high cholesterol if you are prone to cholesterol issues.